# Find replace phrases in a pipe delimited string using TextFinder Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use TextFind to replace whole phrases between pipes in pipe-delimited cell values

I have sht.getRange(1, 1) = `xx?|bob xx?|zzz|xx?ZZZ`

what I get when running `test` is `BIRD|bob BIRD|zzz|BIRDZZZ`

But what I need is `BIRD|bob xx?|zzz|xx?ZZZ`

How to restrict TextFind to the whole phrase separated by the pipes

Thank you

```
function test() {
  var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sht  = ss.getSheetByName("A1");  
  var rng  = sht.getRange(1, 1).createTextFinder("xx?").matchCase(false).replaceAllWith("BIRD");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `useRegularExpression(true)` after the `createTextFinder(search string)` method will configures the search to interpret the search string as a regular expression.

Your code should look like this:

```
function test() {
  var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sht  = ss.getSheetByName("A1");  
  var rng  = sht.getRange(1, 1).createTextFinder("^xx\\?").useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith("BIRD");
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Reference:**

- [useRegularExpression()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#useregularexpressionuseregex)